# Integer overflows when stored into 'Int Phone Number

Tags: ios, swift

In xcode 8, I am getting an error when I try to archive. This is the code:

```
@IBAction func dialNumber(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(8708382937)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

On the line that begins with "if let..." I am getting this error: 
**Integer literal '8708382937' overflows when stored into 'Int'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected and a correct error. Why are you putting the number in `\()`? That evaluates it as Swift. As Swift that's a literal number, which is too big to fit in an Int. You almost certainly mean this:

```
"tel://8708382937"
```

Or more sensibly:

```
"tel:8708382937"
```

(The slashes are specifically part of the HTTP URL-scheme. They are not a general part of URLs and [do not belong on `tel` URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966).)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you taking the time to show me my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to just use a string literal for the URL.

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://8708382937") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```